# Need help - limit access to sftp user to other users home->subfolder

Tags: ssh, sftp, user-management

I have been able to find a lot of help with jailing a user to their own home folder and restricting them only to sftp but I working on a more advanced solution.

What I am trying to do and can't find any docs on is I want to restrict sftp access for a user but give them access to a site folder inside another user's home folder.

Two users - u1 and u2
two home folders - /home/u1 & /home/u2
u1 has a website in a subfolder - /home/u1/public_html/site1/
I want to jail u2 to user u1's site1 folder above.  Could use some help on doing that.

Notes:
- I can't use something like vsftpd because I have the system locked down pretty good.
- user u1's site1 folder's chown is u1:www-data and I would like to be able to keep it that way if possible.  I read that in order to chroot the folder has to be owned by root:root but this would screw things up on the webserver side I think.
- If I need to use vsftpd I just need help understanding how to keep the system secure at the same time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE1:**

added a user u2

setup the private ssh keys

changed the /home/u2 ownership to root:root

modified the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server 
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0002
Match User u2
        ChrootDirectory /home/u2
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

added u2 to the www-data group

added a folder /home/u2/site1

binded the u1 folder I need u2 to have access to with this command:

```
sudo mount --bind /home/u1/public_html/site1/public /home/u2/site1
```

changed all permissions of all files/folders within /home/u2/site1 to include write permissions for the group:

```
chmod -R 775 /home/u2/site1
```

make all future files/folders belong to www-data:

```
chmod g+s /home/u2/site1/
```

switched to both users and made new files/folders have group write permissions:

```
umask 002
```

went in to u2 /home/u2/.bashrc AND /home/u2/.profile and added umask 002 at end of each 
file

Everything is working - u2 can not ssh in but can sftp in and can only see /home/u2 and above.
BUT, I still can't get any new files/folders to automatically have group write permissions.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

**UPDATE2:**

Ok, did a couple of tests. Weird results:

created a folder through sftp with u2 called test and it had the permissions rwxr-sr-x (755 right?) and was able to sftp in as u1 and was able to go into that folder but not upload a file but was able to delete that folder.

As u1 I was able to upload a file and it's permissions became rw-rw-r-- (664) like we have been trying to do.
Also as u1 I created a folder named test2 and it gave the permissions of rwxrwsr-x(775) like we wanted also.

As u2 I am able to sftp into folder 2 and upload a file but the permissions are still rw-r--r-- (644) but CAN delete it with u1 sftp.

I think there is something going on with the jail or something with the u2 account not letting a certain service run or something that will let the proper umask take hold. Thoughts?

**UPDATE3**

Ok, tried something and it worked. Confusion for sure! Hopefully someone can explain why it worked.

In the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file I commented out the line ForceCommand internal-sftp and restarted ssh and it worked. Happy but confused. Thanks.

```
Match User u2
        ChrootDirectory /home/u2
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        #ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If user u2 only needs to access `/home/u1/public_html/site1` via SFTP and is not allowed to access the system in any other way: you can give him that directory as a home directory and follow normal chroot procedures.

---

Alternatively :

A Linux `bind` mount allows you to map one part of an existing file system to a second location in your directory tree. Bind mounts do not change the underlying filesystem permissions.

```
mkdir /home/u2/site1
mount -t bind  /home/u1/public_html/site1 /home/u2/site1
```

User u2 can still be chrooted and if the file system permissions would have allowed him to write in /home/u1/public_html/site1 he can now access that location on /home/u2/site1 from within his chroot.

Comment: mounting the outside the directory inside the user home directory, that should resolve your problem

Comment: Ok, that got me 99% of the way using the bind solution.  BUT, I am struggling with one little piece still.  See my Update1 above.  Thanks.